Does Libvirtd record the start and end timestamps of a session when establishing a connection through the 'virsh' tool?
For instance, when initiating a connection to Libvirtd using the command 'virsh -c qemu+tcp://user@host/system', I attempted to locate the session logs within 'journalctl' and 'audit.log' but was unsuccessful.
Despite adjusting the log settings in '/etc/var/log/libvird.log' as follows:
log_level = 1
audit_level = 2
log_filters = "1:*"
I still could not find the desired information.
